# What is the meaning of this notation of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I find it in a proof, and I don't understand at all.

"*... an orthogonal matrix $D$ satisfying:*

*$D=[d_1,d_2, \dots,d_n]$* *,*  *$d_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbb{1}_n $*"

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D$ has $n$ columns. The $j$-th column of $D$ is $d_j$. The symbol $\mathbb 1_n$ means a vector containing $n$ ones. So, $d_1$, the first column of $D$, is equal to $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}(1,\ldots,1)^T$.

Comment: This is what i thought, but in this case the matrix is not orthogonal

Comment: You cannot tell whether it is orthogonal just knowing the first column.  It could well be orthogonal with those specifications.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification!